# TikZ array of coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I define an array of coordinates in TikZ? Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\vertA}{{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)}}
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
      \coordinate (V\i) at ($\vertA[\i]$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` gives the error:

```
Runaway argument?
\vertA [\i ]$); \pgffor@endhook \ifx \pgffor@assign@after@code \pgfutil@empty \
ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.
```

Comment: `\foreach \i in {0,1,2} {\coordinate (V\i) at (\i,0);}`

Comment: The second coordinate is not always zero..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would go about this differently: Instead of looping over the indices and then accessing the members of the `\vertA` array, you can loop directly over the coordinate array and use the `count=<macro name>` function of `\foreach`.

I couldn't get the `\coordinate (<name>) at (<coordinate>)` command to accept a macro as its coordinate, so I went with the `\coordinate [at=<coordinate macro>`] approach instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand{\vertA}{(0,0),(1,0),(2,3)}
    \foreach \coord [count=\i] in \vertA {
      \coordinate [at=\coord, name=A\i];
    }
    \draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This works..

Comment: Why does not `\coordinate (A\i) at \coord;` work here?

Comment: Don't know. Something with the parser. You can say `\coordinate [at=\coord] (A\i);`, though, if you want